# Spring Boot + React bundling as WebJar with custom context-path for the React app

Tags: reactjs, spring, spring-boot, web

I have a Spring Boot backend application with a React frontend (BFF). So I have my standard spring boot setup from spring initialiser and then with the help of create-react-app, I have generated a front end. So far so good.
I am using gradle to build and bundle all together. Now, in my frontend module, I have the following `build.gradle` file:

```
plugins {
    id "com.github.node-gradle.node" version "2.2.4"
}
apply plugin: 'java'

node {
    version = "12.18.4"
    download = true
}

task bundle(type: NpmTask, dependsOn: npmInstall) {
    args = ['run', 'build']
}

task uiTest(type: NpmTask) {
    environment = ['DEV': 'true']
    args = ['run', 'test']
}

task run(type: NpmTask) {
    args = ['start']
}

check.dependsOn(test)
jar.dependsOn(bundle)

task webjar(type: Jar) {
    from(fileTree("build")) {
        into "META-INF/resources"
    }
}

check.dependsOn(test)
jar.dependsOn(bundle)
jar.finalizedBy('webjar')
```

So as you can see, I am building the frontend as a webjar and then I am adding it to my backend as a dependency:

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(':dashboard-webapp')
}
```

This works great and when I execute `./gradlew bootRun` and go to `localhost:8080` I see my template React project.

But the thing is that I want to add a context-path only for the frontend.
In other words, I want to have the React app under `localhost:8080/dashboard` and I don't know how to do it.

I don't want to change the whole context path for the whole Spring boot application as then I will break other existing controller paths.

I tried the following stuff:

1. added a `.env` file with `PUBLIC_URL=/dashboard` inside
2. tried a `BrowserRouter` component:

```
function App() {

        return (
            <BrowserRouter basename="/dashboard">
                // skipped for clarity
            </BrowserRouter>
    }
```

But unfortunately to no effect.

Now my question is, is this possible with my approch of bundling the frontend app as WebJar? And if so how?

Comment: Since reactjs is served at its own proxy port i recommend not to use create react app when creating your react js app but rather do it step by step and configure your frontend interdependently using weback and babel. That way you will be able to serve your frontend from backend at http://localhost:8080/ . You can checkout a well articulated post i wrote here https://medium.com/swlh/spring-boot-and-react-js-fullstack-application-7ad99139e95c .

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I am already serving my frontend at `localhost:8080`. And I want to change this to `localhost:8080/dashboard` for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I solved it myself with a StaticResourceConfig and not building the frontend as a jar.

```
@Configuration
public class StaticResourceConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/**")
            .addResourceLocations(*path_to_static_file*)
            .resourceChain(true)
            .addResolver(new PathResourceResolver() {
                @Override
                protected Resource getResource(String resourcePath, Resource location) throws IOException {
                    // Show index.html if no resource was found
                    if (!location.createRelative(resourcePath).exists() && !location.createRelative(resourcePath).isReadable()) {
                        return location.createRelative("index.html");
                    } else {
                        return location.createRelative(resourcePath);
                    }
                }
            });
    }
}
```